# Constrain return type based on input parameter type in Scala

Tags: scala

Is it possible to return a specific data type based on what goes in? Let's say I have the following code:

```
sealed trait Super
case class SpecificA(...) extends Super
case class SpecificB(...) extends Super

trait Bells
trait Whistles

sealed trait Something
case class SomeAWithBellsAndWhistles(...) extends Something with Bells with Whistles
case class SomeBWithBellsAndWhistles(...) extends Something with Bells with Whistles

object Utils {
  def doStuff[T <: Super](...): RT
}
```

`RT` can only be `SomeAWithBellsAndWhistles` if `T` is `SpecificA` and similarly for `B`. If I know all the 'allowed' combinations, is there a way to enforce that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for parametrized types?

```
 sealed trait Something[T <: Super] 
 class SomeAWithBellsAndWhistles extends Something[SomeA] with Bells with Whistles
 class SomeBWithBellsAndWhistles extends Something[SomeB] with Bells with Whistles

 def doStuff[T <: Super](...): Something[T]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a type level function to achieve this:

```
trait FindThing[A] {
  type Out
}
object FindThing {
  type Aux[A, B] = FindThing[A] { type Out = B }
  implicit def findA: FindThing.Aux[SpecificA, SomeAWithBellsAndWhistles] =
    new FindThing[SpecificA] {
      type Out = SomeAWithBellsAndWhistles
    }
  implicit def findB: FindThing.Aux[SpecificB, SomeBWithBellsAndWhistles] =
    new FindThing[SpecificB] {
      type Out = SomeBWithBellsAndWhistles
    }
}

def doStuff[T](t: T)(implicit T: FindThing[T]): T.Out =
  ???

def x: SomeAWithBellsAndWhistles = doStuff(SpecificA())
def y: SomeBWithBellsAndWhistles = doStuff(SpecificB())
```

This works by creating an implicit `FindThing` value linking the “input” (e.g. `SpecificA`) and “output” (e.g. `SomeAWithBellsAndWhistles`) types for each permissible combination. Note that this doesn't require the input & output types existing in a particular hierarchy (so e.g. all the input types don't need to extend `Super`).

You also can [emulate functional dependencies](https://milessabin.com/blog/2011/07/16/fundeps-in-scala/) which should be able to achieve the same result I think.